# How do you disable "constructor-style printing" in Racket?

Tags: racket

I've been experimenting with some of DrRacket's language variants, and in one of them, Lazy Racket, the REPL always prints the code to generate the data with constructors, instead of printing out literals. For example:

```
> '(this is dumb)
(list 'this 'is 'dumb)

> '(FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU- . CK)
(cons 'FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU- 'CK)
```

There's even a little bit of documentation on this feature:

http://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/output-syntax.html

But while the documentation paints the output mode as a choice, it neglects to say how to change it. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the menu: Language -> Choose Language. If necessary, choose "show details". Then you can choose the output style. You seem to use Constructor; set to Print.

[image]

Comment: Heh, I see that that dialogue box isn't actually a real OS-level window. I tried using ⇧⌘4 + space, and it only wanted to select the top-level DrRacket window. It's a bummer, because I hate having to manually crop my screenshots. ;-) (Reminds me of the days of trying to debug Swing programs using Spy++. Swing windows aren't real windows, so it's basically impossible.)

Comment: Can this be done from the command line REPL? I notice that the command-line REPL switched from "write" to "print" a few versions ago, and I wouldn't mind seeing those 'tick marks go away when I use Racket from EMACS.

Answer (score 0):

That is wholly controlled by your DrRacket language settings. For example, if you chose Lazy Racket by using `#lang lazy` (and "Determine language from source"), the default output style is `print`. But if you chose Lazy Racket" from the Other Languages section of the languages menu, then the default output style is Constructor.

As uselpa said, click Show Details to see the output style in effect.

By the way, "Determine language from source" is almost always preferred over other ways to select a language.

Comment: I didn't know about #lang lazy. I think choosing it from the menu should have automatically added the #lang lazy line. Do you have any idea how to go into #lang lazy from the REPL as started from the command line?

Comment: @ThrowawayAccount3Million No, you should _not_ use a `#lang` line unless you use "Determine language from source". Which is why you should always use "Determine language from source".

Comment: You can't use "Determine language from source" unless you know the language's proper #lang name. As it currently stands, the only way to learn the language's proper #lang name, if all you have is its "human-friendly" name as shown in the languages menu, is to ask someone on Stack Overflow. There's nothing in DrRacket that allows you to see that "Lazy Racket" corresponds to "#lang lazy".